# Why doesn't my application using winapi redraw text on WM_PAINT messages?

Tags: windows, winapi, rust

I have a Windows application written in Rust and winapi that opens a window and writes text in the client area. The window procedure is as follows:

```
pub unsafe extern "system" fn window_proc(
    hwnd: HWND,
    msg: UINT,
    wparam: WPARAM,
    lparam: LPARAM,
) -> LRESULT {
    match msg {
        WM_CLOSE => {
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        }
        WM_DESTROY => {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        }
        WM_PAINT => {
            println!( "WM_PAINT {}", text.len() );
            let mut ps: PAINTSTRUCT = std::mem::zeroed();
            let t: String = text.to_string();
            let hdc: HDC;
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &mut ps);
            let mut rec: RECT = RECT {top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0};
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &mut rec);
            rec.top += 4;
            rec.left += 6;
            rec.bottom -= 4;
            rec.right -= 6;
            let txt = to_wstring( &t );
            DrawTextW(hdc, txt.as_ptr(), txt.len().try_into().unwrap(), &mut rec, DT_TOP|DT_LEFT);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
        }
        _ => return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam),
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The text in the client area is drawn when the window starts. Then I  continuously change the text and send `WM_PAINT` messages to the window procedure. The messages are received; I can see it in the `println` output. However, the new text is not redrawn. The new text is drawn only when I resize the window; it is not drawn when I move it on the screen, even though it causes a train of `WM_PAINT` messages.

I've also tried `ExtTextOutW` and `TextOutW` instead of `DrawTextW`, but it doesn't change anything except that these two functions cannot handle multi-line texts.

Since the resizing solves the problem, I've also tried to modify the drawing rectangle `rec` at each `WM_PAINT` message, but it doesn't help.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**: Below I include the whole program, including the dependencies, to make reproducing the problem possible.

```
//#![cfg(windows)]
//#![windows_subsystem = "windows"]
//
//[dependencies]
//winapi = { version = "0.3.9", features = ["wingdi", "winuser", "libloaderapi", "combaseapi", "objbase", "shobjidl", "winerror"] }
//lazy_static = "1.4.0"

use std::thread;
use std::time;
use std::error::Error;
use std::ptr::null_mut;
use winapi::shared::minwindef::*;
use winapi::shared::windef::*;
use winapi::um::libloaderapi::{GetModuleHandleW};
use winapi::um::winuser::*;
use lazy_static::{lazy_static};

// Get a win32 lpstr from a &str, converting u8 to u16 and appending '\0'
fn to_wstring(value: &str) -> Vec<u16> {
    use std::os::windows::ffi::OsStrExt;
    std::ffi::OsStr::new(value).encode_wide()
    .chain(std::iter::once(0)).collect()
}

// Window procedure function to handle events
//pub unsafe extern "system" fn window_proc(
pub unsafe extern "system" fn window_proc(
    hwnd: HWND,
    msg: UINT,
    wparam: WPARAM,
    lparam: LPARAM,
) -> LRESULT {
    match msg {
        WM_CLOSE => {
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        }
        WM_DESTROY => {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        }
        WM_PAINT => {
            println!( "WM_PAINT {}", TEXT.len() );
            let mut ps: PAINTSTRUCT = std::mem::zeroed();
            let t: String = TEXT.to_string();
            let hdc: HDC;
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &mut ps);
            let mut rec: RECT = RECT {top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0};
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &mut rec);
            rec.top += 4;
            rec.left += 6;
            rec.bottom -= 4;
            rec.right -= 6;
            let txt = to_wstring( &t );
            DrawTextW(hdc, txt.as_ptr(), txt.len().try_into().unwrap(), &mut rec, DT_TOP|DT_LEFT);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
        }
        _ => return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam),
    }
    return 0;
}

// Declare class and instantiate window
fn create_main_window(name: &str, title: &str) -> Result<HWND, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let name = to_wstring(name);
    let title = to_wstring(title);

    unsafe {
        // Get handle to the file used to create the calling process
        let hinstance = GetModuleHandleW(null_mut());

        // Create and register window class
        let wnd_class = WNDCLASSEXW {
            cbSize: std::mem::size_of::<WNDCLASSEXW>() as u32,
            style: CS_OWNDC | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW,
            lpfnWndProc: Some(window_proc),
            cbClsExtra: 0,
            cbWndExtra: 0,
            hInstance: hinstance, // Handle to the instance that contains the window procedure for the class
            hIcon: LoadIconW(null_mut(), IDI_APPLICATION),
            hCursor: LoadCursorW(null_mut(), IDC_ARROW),
            hbrBackground: COLOR_WINDOWFRAME as HBRUSH,
            lpszMenuName: null_mut(),
            lpszClassName: name.as_ptr(),
            hIconSm: LoadIconW(null_mut(), IDI_APPLICATION),
        };

        // Register window class
        if RegisterClassExW(&wnd_class) == 0 {
            MessageBoxW(
                null_mut(),
                to_wstring("Window Registration Failed!").as_ptr(),
                to_wstring("Error").as_ptr(),
                MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK,
            );
            return Err("Window Registration Failed".into());
        };

        // Create a window based on registered class
        let handle = CreateWindowExW(
            0,                                  // dwExStyle
            name.as_ptr(),                      // lpClassName
            title.as_ptr(),                     // lpWindowName
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,   // dwStyle
            710,                                // Int x
            580,                                // Int y
            700,                                // Int nWidth
            400,                                // Int nHeight
            null_mut(),                         // hWndParent
            null_mut(),                         // hMenu
            hinstance,                          // hInstance
            null_mut(),                         // lpParam
        );

        if handle.is_null() {
            MessageBoxW(
                null_mut(),
                to_wstring("Window Creation Failed!").as_ptr(),
                to_wstring("Error!").as_ptr(),
                MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK,
            );
            return Err("Window Creation Failed!".into());
        }
        Ok(handle)
    }
}

// Message handling loop
fn run_message_loop(hwnd: HWND) -> WPARAM {
    unsafe {
        let mut msg: MSG = std::mem::zeroed();
        loop {
            // Get message from message queue
            if GetMessageW(&mut msg, hwnd, 0, 0) > 0 {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessageW(&msg);
            } else {
                // Return on error (<0) or exit (=0) cases
                return msg.wParam;
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    unsafe { 
        TEXT = T_CONST.clone(); 
    }
    let hwnd = create_main_window("Main Window", "Main Window")
        .expect("Window creation failed!");
    unsafe {
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
        UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    }
    thread::spawn( || {
        loop {
            thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(2000));
            unsafe {
                let t = TEXT.clone();
                TEXT = t + &T_CONST.clone();
                PostMessageW (HWND_BROADCAST as HWND, WM_PAINT, 0 as WPARAM, 0 as LPARAM);
            }
        }
    });
    run_message_loop(hwnd);
}

static mut TEXT: String = String::new();

lazy_static! {
static ref T_CONST: String = "This is the first line of the text
and this is the third line
and now comes the last line
".to_string();
}
```

**SOLUTION**: It's not enough to modify the text to be displayed and send a `WM_PAINT` message. You also have to invalidate the client area. This is conveniently done with a call to `RedrawWindow()`. In a threaded application the best solution is to post a new custom message from the worker thread, receive it in the window procedure, and call `RedrawWindow()`. This is a thread-safe solution.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: @Finomnis: I strongly believe that something is missing in my handling of winapi and that the code and the description is sufficient. The whole program is ca 200 lines. I'll see if I can add it to the question. You cannot run it in Rust Playground and opening a new Cargo project is a little beyond my experience.

Comment: How are people supposed to reproduce your problem if you don't provide runnable code? If you strongly believe that, then leave it, but you won't get any answers if nobody is able to reproduce it. Voting to close.

Comment: *"the code and the description is sufficient"* - To contain the problem? Maybe. To find the problem? Probably not, it's rare that people know enough about a topic so they can find issues by purely looking at them. That's exactly why we need [MRE]s.

Comment: *"new Cargo project is a little beyond my experience"* - it's not that hard :) you simply type `cargo new mre` in some folder, then enter the `mre` folder and run `cargo run`. That's all that's necessary to create a new cargo project. Then you add your code and dependencies. If you don't do it, we have to do it, and we lack the rest of your project, so we can't.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code :) let me see if I can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Finomnis: I've misunderstood "a new Cargo project"; I thought you wanted something on github. `Cargo` is my primary tool.

Comment: I don't know about rust but the way to ask your window to refresh is not good. You should invalidate the client area (use InvalidateRect or UpdateWindow): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/invalidating-the-client-area https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/invalidating-the-client-area PS: you don't need to ReleaseDC since you call EndPaint. In general, you want to read Microsoft Official documentation and try official samples first (rust or not rust).

Comment: @SimonMourier Can't call `InvalidateRect` from a different thread, though, correct?

Comment: @Simon Mourier: OK, I didn't know about `InvalidateRect`. I'll try to add it. It is tricky to do from another thread, as Finomnis points out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems I found:

- Don't call `ReleaseDC` after `EndPaint`, that's already part of `EndPaint`.
- Only regions that weren't rendered yet get updated. You can see that if you drag the window out of the screen and back in, then the regions that were previously off-screen get updated. You can manually invalidate regions via calling `InvalidateRect` or `RedrawWindow`. In your case, you probably want to call `RedrawWindow` instead of sending a `WM_PAINT` message.

```rust
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use std::error::Error;
use std::ptr::{null, null_mut};
use std::thread;
use std::time;
use winapi::shared::minwindef::*;
use winapi::shared::windef::*;
use winapi::um::libloaderapi::GetModuleHandleW;
use winapi::um::winuser::*;

// Get a win32 lpstr from a &str, converting u8 to u16 and appending '\0'
fn to_wstring(value: &str) -> Vec<u16> {
    use std::os::windows::ffi::OsStrExt;
    std::ffi::OsStr::new(value)
        .encode_wide()
        .chain(std::iter::once(0))
        .collect()
}

// Window procedure function to handle events
//pub unsafe extern "system" fn window_proc(
pub unsafe extern "system" fn window_proc(
    hwnd: HWND,
    msg: UINT,
    wparam: WPARAM,
    lparam: LPARAM,
) -> LRESULT {
    match msg {
        WM_CLOSE => {
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        }
        WM_DESTROY => {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        }
        WM_PAINT => {
            println!("WM_PAINT {}", TEXT.len());
            let mut ps: PAINTSTRUCT = std::mem::zeroed();
            let t: String = TEXT.to_string();
            let hdc: HDC;
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &mut ps);
            let mut rec: RECT = RECT {
                top: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
            };
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &mut rec);
            rec.top += 4;
            rec.left += 6;
            rec.bottom -= 4;
            rec.right -= 6;
            let txt = to_wstring(&t);
            DrawTextW(
                hdc,
                txt.as_ptr(),
                txt.len().try_into().unwrap(),
                &mut rec,
                DT_TOP | DT_LEFT,
            );
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }
        _ => return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam),
    }
    return 0;
}

// Declare class and instantiate window
fn create_main_window(name: &str, title: &str) -> Result<HWND, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let name = to_wstring(name);
    let title = to_wstring(title);

    unsafe {
        // Get handle to the file used to create the calling process
        let hinstance = GetModuleHandleW(null_mut());

        // Create and register window class
        let wnd_class = WNDCLASSEXW {
            cbSize: std::mem::size_of::<WNDCLASSEXW>() as u32,
            style: CS_OWNDC | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW,
            lpfnWndProc: Some(window_proc),
            cbClsExtra: 0,
            cbWndExtra: 0,
            hInstance: hinstance, // Handle to the instance that contains the window procedure for the class
            hIcon: LoadIconW(null_mut(), IDI_APPLICATION),
            hCursor: LoadCursorW(null_mut(), IDC_ARROW),
            hbrBackground: COLOR_WINDOWFRAME as HBRUSH,
            lpszMenuName: null_mut(),
            lpszClassName: name.as_ptr(),
            hIconSm: LoadIconW(null_mut(), IDI_APPLICATION),
        };

        // Register window class
        if RegisterClassExW(&wnd_class) == 0 {
            MessageBoxW(
                null_mut(),
                to_wstring("Window Registration Failed!").as_ptr(),
                to_wstring("Error").as_ptr(),
                MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK,
            );
            return Err("Window Registration Failed".into());
        };

        // Create a window based on registered class
        let handle = CreateWindowExW(
            0,                                // dwExStyle
            name.as_ptr(),                    // lpClassName
            title.as_ptr(),                   // lpWindowName
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, // dwStyle
            710,                              // Int x
            580,                              // Int y
            700,                              // Int nWidth
            400,                              // Int nHeight
            null_mut(),                       // hWndParent
            null_mut(),                       // hMenu
            hinstance,                        // hInstance
            null_mut(),                       // lpParam
        );

        if handle.is_null() {
            MessageBoxW(
                null_mut(),
                to_wstring("Window Creation Failed!").as_ptr(),
                to_wstring("Error!").as_ptr(),
                MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK,
            );
            return Err("Window Creation Failed!".into());
        }
        Ok(handle)
    }
}

// Message handling loop
fn run_message_loop(hwnd: HWND) -> WPARAM {
    unsafe {
        let mut msg: MSG = std::mem::zeroed();
        loop {
            // Get message from message queue
            if GetMessageW(&mut msg, hwnd, 0, 0) > 0 {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessageW(&msg);
            } else {
                // Return on error (<0) or exit (=0) cases
                return msg.wParam;
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        TEXT = T_CONST.clone();
    }
    let hwnd = create_main_window("Main Window", "Main Window").expect("Window creation failed!");
    unsafe {
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
        UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    }

    let hwnd2 = hwnd as usize;
    thread::spawn(move || loop {
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(2000));
        unsafe {
            let t = TEXT.clone();
            TEXT = t + &T_CONST.clone();
            RedrawWindow(
                hwnd2 as HWND,
                null(),
                null_mut(),
                RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_ERASE,
            );
        }
    });
    run_message_loop(hwnd);
}

static mut TEXT: String = String::new();

lazy_static! {
    static ref T_CONST: String = "This is the first line of the text
and this is the third line
and now comes the last line
"
    .to_string();
}
```

---

There are a couple more things I would like to remark:

- Global `static mut String` is inherently `unsafe` and incompatible with multiple threads. In fact, the way you implemented it here is undefined behaviour, because the `WM_PAINT` handler could run at the same time as the string gets modified. Use `static Mutex<String>` instead.
- `lazy_static! { static ref T_CONST: String }` is quite pointless; there is a mechanism specifically meant for const strings, it's called `const &str`.
- `&T_CONST.clone()` is pointless, `&T_CONST` (or `T_CONST.as_str()` if it's wrapped in a `lazy_static`) does exactly the same; or after refactoring it to a `const &str`, simply `T_CONST`.
- `HWND_BROADCAST as HWND` is pointless, `HWND_BROADCAST` is already `HWND`.
- Most of the WinAPI functions return `BOOL` for error handling, which you completely ignore. I won't fix that, though, because it's more work than I'm willed to put into this :)

With most of those fixed, this is how the code would look like:

```rust
use std::error::Error;
use std::ptr::{null, null_mut};
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::thread;
use std::time;
use winapi::shared::minwindef::*;
use winapi::shared::windef::*;
use winapi::um::libloaderapi::GetModuleHandleW;
use winapi::um::winuser::*;

// Get a win32 lpstr from a &str, converting u8 to u16 and appending '\0'
fn to_wstring(value: &str) -> Vec<u16> {
    use std::os::windows::ffi::OsStrExt;
    std::ffi::OsStr::new(value)
        .encode_wide()
        .chain(std::iter::once(0))
        .collect()
}

// Window procedure function to handle events
//pub unsafe extern "system" fn window_proc(
pub unsafe extern "system" fn window_proc(
    hwnd: HWND,
    msg: UINT,
    wparam: WPARAM,
    lparam: LPARAM,
) -> LRESULT {
    match msg {
        WM_CLOSE => {
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        }
        WM_DESTROY => {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        }
        WM_PAINT => {
            let t = TEXT.lock().unwrap().clone();
            println!("WM_PAINT {}", t.len());
            let mut ps: PAINTSTRUCT = std::mem::zeroed();
            let hdc: HDC;
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &mut ps);
            let mut rec: RECT = RECT {
                top: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
            };
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &mut rec);
            rec.top += 4;
            rec.left += 6;
            rec.bottom -= 4;
            rec.right -= 6;
            let txt = to_wstring(&t);
            DrawTextW(
                hdc,
                txt.as_ptr(),
                txt.len().try_into().unwrap(),
                &mut rec,
                DT_TOP | DT_LEFT,
            );
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }
        _ => return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam),
    }
    return 0;
}

// Declare class and instantiate window
fn create_main_window(name: &str, title: &str) -> Result<HWND, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let name = to_wstring(name);
    let title = to_wstring(title);

    unsafe {
        // Get handle to the file used to create the calling process
        let hinstance = GetModuleHandleW(null_mut());

        // Create and register window class
        let wnd_class = WNDCLASSEXW {
            cbSize: std::mem::size_of::<WNDCLASSEXW>() as u32,
            style: CS_OWNDC | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW,
            lpfnWndProc: Some(window_proc),
            cbClsExtra: 0,
            cbWndExtra: 0,
            hInstance: hinstance, // Handle to the instance that contains the window procedure for the class
            hIcon: LoadIconW(null_mut(), IDI_APPLICATION),
            hCursor: LoadCursorW(null_mut(), IDC_ARROW),
            hbrBackground: COLOR_WINDOWFRAME as HBRUSH,
            lpszMenuName: null_mut(),
            lpszClassName: name.as_ptr(),
            hIconSm: LoadIconW(null_mut(), IDI_APPLICATION),
        };

        // Register window class
        if RegisterClassExW(&wnd_class) == 0 {
            MessageBoxW(
                null_mut(),
                to_wstring("Window Registration Failed!").as_ptr(),
                to_wstring("Error").as_ptr(),
                MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK,
            );
            return Err("Window Registration Failed".into());
        };

        // Create a window based on registered class
        let handle = CreateWindowExW(
            0,                                // dwExStyle
            name.as_ptr(),                    // lpClassName
            title.as_ptr(),                   // lpWindowName
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, // dwStyle
            710,                              // Int x
            580,                              // Int y
            700,                              // Int nWidth
            400,                              // Int nHeight
            null_mut(),                       // hWndParent
            null_mut(),                       // hMenu
            hinstance,                        // hInstance
            null_mut(),                       // lpParam
        );

        if handle.is_null() {
            MessageBoxW(
                null_mut(),
                to_wstring("Window Creation Failed!").as_ptr(),
                to_wstring("Error!").as_ptr(),
                MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK,
            );
            return Err("Window Creation Failed!".into());
        }
        Ok(handle)
    }
}

// Message handling loop
fn run_message_loop(hwnd: HWND) -> WPARAM {
    unsafe {
        let mut msg: MSG = std::mem::zeroed();
        loop {
            // Get message from message queue
            if GetMessageW(&mut msg, hwnd, 0, 0) > 0 {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessageW(&msg);
            } else {
                // Return on error (<0) or exit (=0) cases
                return msg.wParam;
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    *TEXT.lock().unwrap() = T_CONST.to_string();

    let hwnd = create_main_window("Main Window", "Main Window").expect("Window creation failed!");
    unsafe {
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
        UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    }

    let hwnd2 = hwnd as usize;
    thread::spawn(move || loop {
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(2000));
        *TEXT.lock().unwrap() += T_CONST;
        unsafe {
            RedrawWindow(
                hwnd2 as HWND,
                null(),
                null_mut(),
                RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_ERASE,
            );
        }
    });
    run_message_loop(hwnd);
}

static TEXT: Mutex<String> = Mutex::new(String::new());

const T_CONST: &str = "This is the first line of the text
and this is the third line
and now comes the last line
";
```

---

### Alternative: Don't use a thread

The best practice for working with UI is to not use threads; or if you do, only use UI-related calls from the main thread.

Here is a version with a timer that achieves the same thing:

```rust
use std::error::Error;
use std::ptr::{null, null_mut};
use std::sync::Mutex;
use winapi::shared::minwindef::*;
use winapi::shared::windef::*;
use winapi::um::libloaderapi::GetModuleHandleW;
use winapi::um::winuser::*;

// Get a win32 lpstr from a &str, converting u8 to u16 and appending '\0'
fn to_wstring(value: &str) -> Vec<u16> {
    use std::os::windows::ffi::OsStrExt;
    std::ffi::OsStr::new(value)
        .encode_wide()
        .chain(std::iter::once(0))
        .collect()
}

const IDT_TIMER1: usize = 1;

// Window procedure function to handle events
//pub unsafe extern "system" fn window_proc(
pub unsafe extern "system" fn window_proc(
    hwnd: HWND,
    msg: UINT,
    wparam: WPARAM,
    lparam: LPARAM,
) -> LRESULT {
    match msg {
        WM_CLOSE => {
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        }
        WM_DESTROY => {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        }
        WM_TIMER => match wparam {
            IDT_TIMER1 => {
                *TEXT.lock().unwrap() += T_CONST;
                RedrawWindow(hwnd, null(), null_mut(), RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_ERASE);
            }
            _ => (),
        },
        WM_PAINT => {
            let t = TEXT.lock().unwrap().clone();
            println!("WM_PAINT {}", t.len());
            let mut ps: PAINTSTRUCT = std::mem::zeroed();
            let hdc: HDC;
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &mut ps);
            let mut rec: RECT = RECT {
                top: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
            };
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &mut rec);
            rec.top += 4;
            rec.left += 6;
            rec.bottom -= 4;
            rec.right -= 6;
            let txt = to_wstring(&t);
            DrawTextW(
                hdc,
                txt.as_ptr(),
                txt.len().try_into().unwrap(),
                &mut rec,
                DT_TOP | DT_LEFT,
            );
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }
        _ => return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam),
    }
    return 0;
}

// Declare class and instantiate window
fn create_main_window(name: &str, title: &str) -> Result<HWND, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let name = to_wstring(name);
    let title = to_wstring(title);

    unsafe {
        // Get handle to the file used to create the calling process
        let hinstance = GetModuleHandleW(null_mut());

        // Create and register window class
        let wnd_class = WNDCLASSEXW {
            cbSize: std::mem::size_of::<WNDCLASSEXW>() as u32,
            style: CS_OWNDC | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW,
            lpfnWndProc: Some(window_proc),
            cbClsExtra: 0,
            cbWndExtra: 0,
            hInstance: hinstance, // Handle to the instance that contains the window procedure for the class
            hIcon: LoadIconW(null_mut(), IDI_APPLICATION),
            hCursor: LoadCursorW(null_mut(), IDC_ARROW),
            hbrBackground: COLOR_WINDOWFRAME as HBRUSH,
            lpszMenuName: null_mut(),
            lpszClassName: name.as_ptr(),
            hIconSm: LoadIconW(null_mut(), IDI_APPLICATION),
        };

        // Register window class
        if RegisterClassExW(&wnd_class) == 0 {
            MessageBoxW(
                null_mut(),
                to_wstring("Window Registration Failed!").as_ptr(),
                to_wstring("Error").as_ptr(),
                MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK,
            );
            return Err("Window Registration Failed".into());
        };

        // Create a window based on registered class
        let handle = CreateWindowExW(
            0,                                // dwExStyle
            name.as_ptr(),                    // lpClassName
            title.as_ptr(),                   // lpWindowName
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, // dwStyle
            710,                              // Int x
            580,                              // Int y
            700,                              // Int nWidth
            400,                              // Int nHeight
            null_mut(),                       // hWndParent
            null_mut(),                       // hMenu
            hinstance,                        // hInstance
            null_mut(),                       // lpParam
        );

        if handle.is_null() {
            MessageBoxW(
                null_mut(),
                to_wstring("Window Creation Failed!").as_ptr(),
                to_wstring("Error!").as_ptr(),
                MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK,
            );
            return Err("Window Creation Failed!".into());
        }
        Ok(handle)
    }
}

// Message handling loop
fn run_message_loop(hwnd: HWND) -> WPARAM {
    unsafe {
        let mut msg: MSG = std::mem::zeroed();
        loop {
            // Get message from message queue
            if GetMessageW(&mut msg, hwnd, 0, 0) > 0 {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessageW(&msg);
            } else {
                // Return on error (<0) or exit (=0) cases
                return msg.wParam;
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    *TEXT.lock().unwrap() = T_CONST.to_string();

    let hwnd = create_main_window("Main Window", "Main Window").expect("Window creation failed!");
    unsafe {
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
        UpdateWindow(hwnd);
        SetTimer(hwnd, IDT_TIMER1, 2000, None);
    }

    run_message_loop(hwnd);
}

static TEXT: Mutex<String> = Mutex::new(String::new());

const T_CONST: &str = "This is the first line of the text
and this is the third line
and now comes the last line
";
```

Comment: Calling InvalidateRect in WM_PAINT is strange (risks infinite loops by design), and posting WM_PAINT message should be avoided https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803009/c-win32-calling-wm-paint-from-another-thread-using-sendmessage-drawing-has-n you can use InvalidateRect from another thread (basically you can use all message-sending functions from any thread since it will end up piling a message in the window message queue)

Comment: You sure? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42896439/calling-updatewindow-from-a-secondary-thread

Comment: @SimonMourier [This one here](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32/c/nBeYBd2lde4) says... maybe? I'd like to have more than "maybe" before recommending it in an answer.

Comment: @SimonMourier Like this? (Updated code and text)

Comment: Also, btw, @KalleSvensson the *"I strongly believe [...] that the code and the description is sufficient"* turns out to be wrong, the problem isn't in the initial code you showed. There are reasons why rules like providing a [MRE] exist.

Comment: @Finomnis: It works. But I'm uncertain about **the thread safety of this solution**. I think sending a message, perhaps a new one, could be safer. But even more safe would be to send a signal to the main thread and have it send a message to the window. This would add a channel. I can do it, the rectangle invalidate was new, the rest I can fix. THANK YOU for improving my Rust code!

Comment: Yes, the code seems correct with your last update (InvalidateRect, UpdateWindow, RedrawWindow, etc. are all related)

Comment: This proposed answer should, undoubtedly, suggest using a [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/timer-overviews). Adding a thread is generally the last thing you'd ever want to do, particularly when it comes to GUI programming. It'll just complicate things so much, and generally doesn't improve performance nor robustness.

Comment: @IInspectable: The real text is produced in an internet access and is done in a separate thread, you cannot help it. The above code only simulates this part.

Comment: @Finomnis: OK, Finomnis, how about making it perfect? Add a `channel`, send a signal from the work thread to the main thread, and `RedrawWindow` in the main thread?

Comment: @Finomnis: By the way. I have this program in C#. In C# you are not allowed to touch GUI from a work thread. The app crashes if you try. There must be good reasons for this.

Comment: @KalleSvensson You can't just send a channel to the main thread, because there is no point where you could wait for said channel. The main thread is always inside of the event loop.

Comment: @IInspectable Added a third example based on a timer.

Comment: @Finomnis: yes, you are right. Then my best solution is to add a new signal, `WM_EXTRA`, receive it in the window procedure and there do the job, or only invalidate rectangle and post a new `WM_PAINT`. 

A solution without a thread is inadequate, I've explained it already.

Comment: @Finomnis: Could you explain the trick with `let hwnd2 = hwnd as usize;` and then `hwnd2 as HWND`? I've tried something similar but without type change, and the Rust compiler protests. I've tried to add a signal. 0x1234, and post it to the window procedure. It works! I think this is the safest way.

Comment: @KalleSvensson Yes, the approach with the new signal sounds valid. `usize` is defined to be an unsigned integer with the same size as a pointer, so you can cast back and forth between them. I just used it here to convince Rust that it's fine to move it to a thread, because `*mut` is not `Send` or `Sync` and can't be copied/moved to a thread.

Comment: @KalleSvensson But note that if you use `HWND_BROADCAST`, it goes to **all** windows in the system, not just yours.